# Can someone explain what is the difference in packages: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce to org.apache.hadoop.mapred?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

It is very confusing, and I don't understand from the javadoc which one should I use.
Additionally the C'tor of the Job class is deprecated in the .mapreduce package. Why?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the mapred packages are deprecated. You should use since 0.20.x the new stuff inside mapreduce package. 
For example the new way to implement a mapper, with mapred-package you have to implement the mapper interface. With the mapreduce-package you simply extend from a basic mapper class and override just the method you need.